# Simple Question on Calculating percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

All -

It has been a while since I ever used Math. This is a very simple problem. How do I calculate the percentage of the following

Suppose I have 30 apples, and out of 30 Apples, 10 apples have become rotten, what is the percentage of apples that have become rotten?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply divide $10$ by $30$ and multiply by $100$ to get the percentage.

$$\frac{10\;\text{rotten apples}}{30\;\text{apples in all}} \times 100\% = \text{percentage of rotten apples}$$

That gives you that $\;\dfrac 13 \times 100\% = 33.\overline{33}\%\;$ of the apples are rotten.

Comment: You're welcome, @fn79 !

Comment: @amWhy: It is OK +